# How to add padding between label and control on FormControlLabel

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to have an inline form, where the label is left to the control which doesn't seem to be default usage of various form components.

So far this does the trick:

```
<Grid container spacing={0}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
        <FormControlLabel
            label="ID"
            disabled
            value="42a5936e-9856-42d4-b540-104fd79bcf36"
            labelPlacement="start"
            control={
                <TextField fullWidth name="ID" />
            }
        />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But there is no space at all between the label and the control.

Here's what it looks like

[image]

I assume some `padding-right` has to be added to the label, but I'm not sure where I would put that using these components.

Comment: A related question that comes to mind: How the hell is that the default behaviour of a component library like MUI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `style` to the props of `TextField`:

```
<Grid container spacing={0}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
        <FormControlLabel
            label="ID"
            disabled
            value="42a5936e-9856-42d4-b540-104fd79bcf36"
            labelPlacement="start"
            control={
                <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    name="ID"
                    style={{ paddingLeft: '20px' }}
                />
            }
        />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Alternatively, `TextField` takes a `className` prop for you to add classes to the components and style those classes.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the Textfield input zone padding:

Use MUI [nesting selector](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors) of className **MuiInputBase-root**

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
      paddingLeft: 10
    }
  }
}));

const classes = useStyles();

control={<TextField fullWidth name="ID" className={classes.root} />}
```

[image]

---

For inline style

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```js
<TextField
   value="42a5936e-9856-42d4-b540-104fd79bcf36"
   fullWidth
   InputProps={{
     startAdornment: (<InputAdornment position="start">ID</InputAdornment>)
   }}
/>
```